# How to parse inside a json array in a table to fetch the sql query php

Tags: sql, json

I have a json array in a table called `contact`. It is like :

```
{"1":{"phone":"565644"},"2":{"phone":"6454654"},"3":{"phone":"654654"},"4":{"phone":"654654"},"5":{"phone":"654654"}}
```

the column name of this table is `phone` and above mentioned value is one record of that column.

Now I want to query the table `contact` to fetch the record which has phone number `6454654`

How to acheive this

Comment: You should normalize your database. You could for example add an additional table with phone numbers that you can link to your contact information table.

Comment: so there is no other way to achieve with the existing table without normalizing it ?

Comment: What database vendor and version are you using? In MySQL 5.7, there is a command called `JSON_CONTAINS()`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

Comment: If it is a text field, you could do a simple: `phone LIKE '%"123456"%'`... It won't be as quick as with normalized data, as suggested by @jeroen.

Comment: You are talking both from json and table. What do you plan to do? Save your json in mysql db then to look for the specified phone number ? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @zeflex yes indeed that's what i am trying to achieve

Comment: so in Json_Contains do i have to query like this select * from contact where json_contains(phone, "phone":"565644"); ?

Comment: @user3470929 do you really need mysql db for that ? because you can retrieve the id associated by converting your json to an array, then do an array_flip

Comment: @zeflex but i have data stored in that fashion already so i have to retreive data based on phone number only which is already saved in db so

Comment: @user3470929 SELECT * FROM table WHERE phone = '6454654' doesn't work ?

Comment: no it wont save like that coz the problem is phone colum data is stored in json format as i have stated in the question

Comment: In this case, I think you got the answer in some of previous comments to look for the number directly with one query ...

Comment: @zeflex can you guide me through the query which i can use ?

Comment: @user3470929 I upvoted the questions that can be a start for your solution.

Comment: @zeflex sure thank you for upvoting